# Json.NET async support with custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Json.NET [version 10 added support to async](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2017/03/21/json-net-10-0-release-1-async-performance-documentation-and-more) serialization.
[Version 11](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more) added support to generic `JsonConverter<T>`.

The problem is that `JsonConverter<T>` and previous `JsonConverter` only support synchronous methods.

i.e.: `public override void WriteJson(...)`

The `JsonWriter` passed to `WriterJson` supports both synchronous and asynchronous methods like:

`writer.WritePropertyNameAsync()` and `writer.WritePropertyName()`

But since `WriteJson` itself is synchronous, the async option is not usable here.

Is it possible to have a custom `JsonConverter` with async methods?

Comment: Why don't u just use  Task.Run(new Action(WriteJson));

Comment: I'd be blocking a thread pool thread that way. The serialized object will written async due to I/O

Comment: Why don't you create a feature request issue in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)?

Comment: I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. There might be a different approach to this that I'm unaware.

Comment: I think it's not yet supported. There is related (but not the same) open issue about `JsonConvert.SerializeAsync` here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1193

Comment: @BrunoGarcia but the thread is not gonna be blocked if u await the Task. is that wrong? so what is the purpose of creating new Task then?

Comment: @ArgeKumandan I want to avoid using threads that are not needed instead of scheduling even more.

Comment: @Evk thanks for that thread! I subscribed to it and I believe the result of that will be the answer to this thread.

Comment: Note that it's over the year old, so don't put much hopes into that being available soon :) Note that you can parse to JToken first (async) and then serialize to specific type with JToken.ToObject (no async needed at this point anyway).

Comment: I'm trying to serialize an object though. Writing to the stream directly to avoid allocating the whole thing in memory at any one point. That part is covered, missing only async with custom JsonConverter.

Comment: Yes I missed you are serializing. I thought to suggest `JToken.FromObject`, but since you don't want to hold whole object in memory also - I see no way with current api indeed.

Comment: Not sure why you want your JsonConverter to read/write asynchronously? At that time you are already provided with a writer and reader injected by the invoking serializer and I can't think of actual IO that could block your thread?

Comment: Related though not duplicate: [Deserializing to AsyncEnumerable using Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72451669/3744182).