# Performance issue with deserializing large JSON file into objects and add them to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, json.net

I'm working on asp.net core 7 MVC project,
and want to seed list of countries with cities to Database from locally stored json file (more than 600000 lines)

Here is a sample of JSON file

```json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "iso3": "AFG",
    "iso2": "AF",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 141,
        "name": "‘Alāqahdārī Dīshū"
      },
      {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Aībak"
      },
      {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Andkhoy"
      },
      {
        "id": 136,
        "name": "Āqchah"
      },
      {
        "id": 137,
        "name": "Ārt Khwājah"
      },
      {
        "id": 51,
        "name": "Asadabad"
      },
      {
        "id": 52,
        "name": "Ashkāsham"
      },
      {
        "id": 138,
        "name": "Āsmār"
      },
      {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Baghlān"
      },
      {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Balkh"
      },
    ]
  } 
]
```

This is what I tried to do.

Country Model:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISO2 { get; set; }
    public string ISO3 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

City Model

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Code for deserializing

```
public static async Task SeedCountries(AppDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment web)
{
    if (!(context.Countries.Count() > 0) || !(context.Cities.Count() > 0))
    {
        string json = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(web.ContentRootPath, "countries.json"));
        var jsonObject = JArray.Parse(json);

        IList<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
        foreach (var item in jsonObject)
        {
            Country country = item.ToObject<Country>();
            var citites = item["cities"] as JArray;
            var citis = new City();
            countries.Add(country);
            foreach (var city in citites)
            {
                City cities = city.ToObject<City>();
                cities.CountryId = country.Id;
                context.Cities.Add(cities);
                context.Entry(cities).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
        await context.Countries.AddRangeAsync(countries);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem with that is performance as its shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: There is no problem in that image. Can you explain in your own words what the problem is? There are of course better ways to read a larger JSON file than to first read it as a string in memory and then parse it entirely.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491910/

Comment: my problem is that memory usage initilly goes upto 3 gb for a few minutes, i can face issues with hosting

Comment: Yeah so don't read and deserialize everything at once, stream it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. You are loading your entire  600000 lines JSON file into a single `json` string.  This string will be much larger than 85,000 bytes so will be added to the large object heap, causing problems described in *[Why Large Object Heap and why do we care?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836/3744182)*.
2. You are then parsing that huge string into a `JArray` which will take up even more memory.

I reckon you are creating the intermediate JSON string because you need to use asynchronous file reading, but Json.NET's serializer does not support `async` deserialization.  However, `JsonTextReader` does support asynchronous reading via [`JsonTextReader.ReadAsync()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader_ReadAsync.htm) and `JToken` does support asynchronous loading via [`Token.LoadAsync()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_LoadAsync_1.htm).  Putting those together, it is possible to iterate through a huge JSON array asynchronously, load each item into a `JToken` asynchronously, then deserialize the token to your final array item (here `Country`) with bounded memory use.

And in fact, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502371/3744182) to *[Deserializing to AsyncEnumerable using Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72451669/3744182)* has an extension method that does exactly that:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously load and synchronously deserialize values from a stream containing a JSON array.  The root object of the JSON stream must in fact be an array, or an exception is thrown
    /// </summary>
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T?> DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T>(Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings? settings = default, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502371/3744182 for the body of this method
```

So grab all the code from the `JsonExtensions` extension class from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502371/3744182), and now you will be able to create your `countries` list as follows:

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(web.ContentRootPath, "countries.json");

var countries = new List<Country>();

await using var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
await foreach (var country in JsonExtensions.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Country>(stream))
{
    if (country == null)
        continue;
    if (country.Cities != null)
        foreach (var city in country.Cities)
        {
            // Do you need another instance of City?  If so you may clone the current one as follows:
            // city = JToken.FromObject(city).ToObject<City>();
            city.CountryId = country.Id;
            context.Cities.Add(city);
            context.Entry(city).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
        }
    countries.Add(country);
}
```

Notes:

- In your sample code, you seem to be deserializing `Cities` twice.  `item.ToObject<Country>();` will deserialize the `Country.Cities` list, but then you deserialize them again manually in your `foreach (var city in citites)` loop.  It's unclear why you are doing this since the list of cities is already present under the country, so I removed the duplication from my sample code

  If for some reason you do you need to create two instances of each `City`, you may need to clone them (e.g. by round-tripping them with the JSON serializer) inside the `foreach (var city in country.Cities)` loop in my sample code.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKJfCn).

**As an alternative**, as suggested by [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159862/performance-issue-with-deserlizing-large-json-file-into-objects-and-add-them-to#comment132631106_75159862), you could switch to System.Text.Json, which has built-in support for asynchronous deserialization of huge JSON arrays via [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable?view=net-7.0):

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var countries = new List<Country>();

await using var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    //PropertyNameCaseInsensitive is required to deserialize "iso2" and "iso3" correctly
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
};
await foreach (var country in JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Country>(stream, options))
{
    if (country == null)
        continue;
    if (country.Cities != null)
        foreach (var city in country.Cities)
        {
            // Do you need another instance of City?  If so you may clone the current one as follows:
            // city = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<City>(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(city));
            city.CountryId = country.Id;
            context.Cities.Add(city);
            context.Entry(city).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
        }
    countries.Add(country);
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v256Q4).